# IOS- tap on textarea crash in WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in my UIView, and the website come up perfectly but the I try to click onto the text area then the app crashed and show these error
I am using IOS 10 and Xcode10

> 2018-11-08 10:24:36.696196+0800 Woofast[14202:3844530] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x129d9d210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = > returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
>
> > 2018-11-08 10:24:36.696349+0800 Woofast[14202:3844530] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x129d9d210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = > returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
> >
> > > 2018-11-08 10:24:36.736874+0800 Woofast[14202:3844530] -[UILayoutGuide flk_nameTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281af7640
> > >
> > > > 2018-11-08 10:24:36.740269+0800 Woofast[14202:3844530] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILayoutGuide flk_nameTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281af7640'
> > > >         *** First throw call stack:
> > > >         (0x1e7647ef8 0x1e6815a40 0x1e755f154 0x1e764d810 0x1e764f4bc 0x106804d68 0x1e7534fdc 0x1e80f4eac 0x1e75f3a4c 0x1e75f51b8 0x1e7fc3e6c 0x213dbcd34 0x213dbcec0 0x1e8033ec4 0x1e802ad94 0x1e802a514 0x1e8029a50 0x1e802979c 0x1e8029020 0x213da70b4 0x213da7534 0x213da7c34 0x213da9990 0x213da9a68 0x1e7fe551c 0x213da9a30 0x213da9f24 0x213db6fec 0x213db5b54 0x213db6004 0x213db5ed8 0x213db5ed8 0x213db5ed8 0x213db5ed8 0x213db5ed8 0x1e7fe551c 0x213db67a8 0x213db513c 0x213db63c8 0x213da63ac 0x213db73e8 0x214564fe0 0x213c87840 0x213d97180 0x213c98250 0x21456ba34 0x213c97f74 0x213c8fc4c 0x213d5e0ec 0x213d57328 0x214281868 0x1f6f2bad4 0x1f71d1d48 0x1f71dd934 0x1f6fc4cd8 0x1f723f5ac 0x1f6f874ac 0x1f6f89c3c 0x1ee9190f0 0x1ee9193b8 0x1e75d65b8 0x1e75d6538 0x1e75d5e1c 0x1e75d0ce8 0x1e75d05b8 0x1e9844584 0x213ecb558 0x104c45634 0x1e7090b94)
> > > >
> > > > > libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityindicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var currentrideid = ""

 var ProductLink = ""

var urlString = ""
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    ProductLink = API_URL.commondomain + "Application/View_Ride_info/\(currentrideid)_\(GlobalVarible.languagecode)"
    print(ProductLink)

    let url = URL(string: ProductLink)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)



    activityindicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityindicator.startAnimating()
    webView.load(request)
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    activityindicator.stopAnimating()

    if let yourTargetUrl = webView.url
    {
        urlString = yourTargetUrl.absoluteString

        print(yourTargetUrl)

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have incorrect outlets set in the inspector. you probably linked an element to an @IBOutlet and then changed the spelling of you variable in the code or in your inspector, you have linked your element to an incorrect @IBOutlet

Comment: thank for u comments, but I have checked, it is not the reason cause the error